# MVC - TemplateEditor = SAVE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Good day!

I created a template editor to address, it is working to populate the screen. The situation that can not revolve, and when you save the data to address MODEL return null.

Editor Call

```
    View Principal
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idEmpresa)

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="data-block main-box clearfix portlet">
                    <section>
                        <div class="form-horizontal" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @*Razao Social*@
                                <div class="col-lg-7">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.razaoSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.razaoSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.razaoSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>

                                @*Nome Fantasia*@
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nomeFantasia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nomeFantasia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nomeFantasia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>                        

                            </div>

                        </div>                 

                        <div class="form-horizontal" style="white-space: nowrap;">

                            <div class="form-group">

                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Endereco.cshtml", @Model.endereco);                                                

                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.complemento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.complemento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.complemento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class=""><br /></div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Gravar alterações da empresa" class="btn btn-info pull-right" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
```

View Address

```
@model MyApp.WebApp.Models.DatabaseModels.Endereco
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })        
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control endereco-cep" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <input type="button" onclick="GetDetalhesCEP()" value="Buscar CEP" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-7">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nomeLogradouro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nomeLogradouro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nomeLogradouro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nomeBairro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nomeBairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nomeBairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cidade.nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cidade.nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cidade.nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cidade.unidadeFederativa.sigla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cidade.unidadeFederativa.sigla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cidade.unidadeFederativa.sigla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
    </div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom/get-address-details.js")
}
```

The Model Controller reading Return

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/622769 - Image

At the moment I click Recording Model address are empty.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/622772 - Image

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your partial is outside the form tags, so its values wont post back (you have 2 of them!). And you controls are not named correctly (not properly prefixed because you use a partial, not an `EditorTemplate`)

Comment: Thank U. After your tip. Managed to solve. Thank you very much.